# visual studio community 2013 and 2015 crash with setup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, visual-studio-2015, vs-community-edition

I have a big problem with my Visual studio community installation, I can't uninstall visual studio community 2013 and 2015, i've also tried to repair but vs_community.exe crashes.

Here is the most interesting part of the log from vs_community.exe startup

```
    [337C:3BB0][2015-12-16T16:00:40]i052: Condition 'NOT NetFX45OrNewer_Release OR NetFX45OrNewer_Release < 378389' evaluates to false.
[337C:3BB0][2015-12-16T16:00:40]i052: Condition '(Win10ToolsVersion = "14.0.22823") AND (IsDateWithinRange = "1")' evaluates to false.
[337C:3BB0][2015-12-16T16:00:40]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (netfxfullredist_43_DetectKey < v4.5.23026)' evaluates to false.
[337C:3BB0][2015-12-16T16:00:40]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed
[337C:3BB0][2015-12-16T16:00:40]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:40]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed, now create view
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:40]i000: MUX:  Local copy of the dynamic feed is present: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\LastUsedFeed\{2bf5d8f9-3960-4c3f-bc58-b4414008639b}\Feed.xml
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:40]i000: MUX:  Feed uri to register: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=558779&clcid=0x410
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:43]i000: MUX:  isOnlineFeedLoaded: True
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:43]i000: MUX:  Final feed location: C:\Users\ANDREA\AppData\Local\Temp\-913613238.xml
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]e000: MUX:  ERROR: L'inizializzatore di tipo di 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily' ha generato un'eccezione.
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]e000: MUX:  Stack:    in System.Windows.Media.Typeface..ctor(FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle style, FontWeight weight, FontStretch stretch)
   in MS.Internal.Text.DynamicPropertyReader.GetTypeface(DependencyObject element)
   in MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties.InitCommon(DependencyObject target)
   in MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties..ctor(FrameworkElement target, Boolean isTypographyDefaultValue)
   in System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.GetLineProperties()
   in System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.EnsureTextBlockCache()
   in System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   in System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   in System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
   in System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   in System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   in System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   in System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   in System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
   in System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   in System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowImpl()
   in System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindow()
   in System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   in System.Windows.Window.Show()
   in Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.RunUI(ViewModelCommonUi viewModel)
   in Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.InternalRun()
   in Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.Run()
   in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]e000: MUX:  Exception: Info: InnerException: Info:
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]e000: MUX:  ERROR: URI non valido: impossibile determinare il formato dell'URI.
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]e000: MUX:  Stack:    in System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   in System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
   in MS.Internal.FontCache.FontSourceCollection.SetFontSources()
   in MS.Internal.FontCache.FontSourceCollection.GetEnumerator()
   in MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.BuildFamilyList(List`1& familyList, SortedDictionary`2& familyNameList, SortedList`2& frequentStrings)
   in MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.MS.Internal.FontCache.IFontCacheElement.AddToCache(CheckedPointer newPointer, ElementCacher cacher)
   in MS.Internal.FontCache.HashTable.Lookup(IFontCacheElement e, Boolean add)
   in MS.Internal.FontCache.CacheManager.Lookup(IFontCacheElement e)
   in System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.PreCreateDefaultFamilyCollection()
   in System.Windows.Media.FontFamily..cctor()
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: ShouldSendData=True
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Permission to upload: Yes
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Preparing to serialize data.
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Data serialized.
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Number of SQM File queued: 0
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  SQM sent: True
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: Setting string variable 'CEIPConsent' to value ''
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: Setting string variable 'SqmOption' to value ''
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: Configuration State
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  ----------------------------
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 426 = 0
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 8 = 31
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 596 = 5.0.0.0
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 439 = vs_community
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 457 = 14.0.23107.10.02
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 440 = 14.0.23107
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 573 = d14rel
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 450 = 1040
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 15 = 4
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 16 = 216
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1191 = 9
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1193 = 1024
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1194 = 8192
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1189 = Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           W3565  @ 3.20GHz
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 3 = 8194
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 493 = 100733329
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 424 = 44877
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 453 = 6.1.7601.65536
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 13 = 1040
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 841 = 0
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 438 = 1
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 616 = 0
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 494 = ct!!0F1A78C32EF14429ADAE8AF8E41312D1
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 599 = 7
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 529 = False
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 833 = False
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 834 = False
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 563 = 800000004006
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1063 = False
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 564 = True
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1599 = f1f2f831-75ed-4a80-aeea-58871879bbaf
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1632 = True
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1633 = True
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1631 = 379
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1631 = 379
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 838 = 0800
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 439 = vs_community
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 457 = 14.0.23107.10.02
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 440 = 14.0.23107
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 437 = 8
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 461 = 
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 517 = Crash: Exception
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 515 = 559b70d9
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 501 = 42a
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 642 = 18
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 824 = 0
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 823 = 0
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 434 = 4
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Watson Bucketting Parameters
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  P1 - vs_community
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  P2 - 14.0.23107.10.02
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  P3 - 14.0.23107
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  P4 - Modify
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  P5 - 
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  P6 - Crash: Exception
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  P7 - 559b70d9
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  P8 - 42a
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  P9 - 18
[337C:31FC][2015-12-16T16:00:44]i000: MUX:  Adding Install Log to Watson=c:\log.txt
```

Why System.Windows.Media.FontFamily make an exception?

I'm using Windows 7 Professional on a workstation and visual studio has an italian Langpack.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I finally managed to solve the problem.
In Windows registry at this key

"**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts**"

I found some keys with values ​​like "/monos.ttf", once deleted the setup has begun to function properly